Can editing a closed and deleted question send it to the reopen review queue?
On an SE site where I'm a regular, I’ve noticed several closed and deleted questions that might be worth reopening due to recent changes in site policy / community consensus. Because there’s no dedicated review queue for undeleting questions, I’d like to bring these to the community’s attention through the reopen review queue.
My plan is to edit these questions to improve their quality and make them suitable for undeletion and reopening. After editing, I'd check the box that says "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening." But here's where I'm uncertain: will this actually put the question into the reopen review queue?
It's worth noting that it takes 10K rep to vote for undeletion, but only 3K to vote for reopening. So, I'm specifically curious about what happens when I edit a closed and deleted question (assuming it wasn't deleted by a moderator, so regular users can vote to undelete it).
I've considered testing this myself, but there are some unknown factors that could prevent a question from appearing in the reopen review queue for specific reviewers. This makes it difficult for me to confirm the results on my own.
Does anyone know if this approach would work? It seems like it could be a useful way to resurrect valuable questions that were closed and deleted under old policies.
I've read the "When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?" MSE post, but this specific scenario is not addressed there. My question is also different from what's covered there.

Since this seems to be based on "recent changes in site policy / community consensus" for some unnamed SE sites, this suggestion would be better discussed in the meta for those sites, rather than here in the abstract.  See for example the canonical reopen/undelete thread on meta Math.SE.

@hardmath My question is actually about the mechanics of the SE review queue system. I'm not seeking a discussion on which questions to reopen or undelete (as in the Math SE meta post you mentioned), but rather asking about whether editing can push deleted questions into the reopen queue. This is a platform-wide technical question relevant to all SE sites.

There is a known quirk that a deleted Question can be reopened but remain deleted.  Of course deleted Questions are not generally visible except to 10k users and moderators, so the reopen votes would only be available to those users with privilege to view deleted Questions.  Such users can indeed vote to reopen, regardless of whether they first edit the Question or not.  I think the reopen review queue is limited by this lack of visibility.

If the questions have no answers or valuable comment discussions, why not just repost them in their acceptable form?

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'd hesitate to repost others' questions; it seems like bad form, especially if the OP is still active on the site. Better to help them improve it instead.

This question is similar to: When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I've read that MSE post, but this specific scenario I described is not addressed in an answer there. My question is also different from what's being asked there.

Doesn't work
It goes to the reopen queue, but is almost immediately invalidated and removed because the question is still deleted.


Thanks for testing this out. It seems the "for reopening" checkbox is pretty much pointless for deleted questions.
